# "Devalued" vs "Devaluated"?

Tags: word-usage, tenses

I have just come across the use of the word "devaluated" in a published book and am wondering if this is a legitimate word as I can't find this past participle in any dictionary. I would think "devalued" would be correct. If not, why would one use "devaluated" in this context instead?

> This is obviously not to suggest that CO<sub>2</sub> emissions should be categorised as acts of terrorism, which would also constitute conceptual abuse, although arguably of a lesser sort, insofar as blind killing is central to what terrorism is. The term should not be **devaluated**, the crime not trivialised.
>
> — *[How to blow up a pipeline](https://www.google.co.uk/books/edition/How_to_Blow_Up_a_Pipeline/AF4NEAAAQBAJ?hl=en&gbpv=1&pg=PA108&printsec=frontcover),* Andreas Malm; Verso Books 2021

Comment: Include in your question your results from looking in a dictionary.

Comment: Devaluate sounds like some bastard child of "evaluate" - I would avoid it.

Comment: It's a back formation from _devaluation_, with the usual _-ation_ suffix. Somebody broke it off in the wrong place. Happens all the time, ignore it.

Answer (score 5):

*Devaluate* doesn't appear in [Cambridge](https://dictionary.cambridge.org/spellcheck/english/?q=devaluate) or [Macmillan](https://www.macmillandictionary.com/spellcheck/british/?q=devaluate) although it does appear in [M-W](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/devaluate).

OED indicates that *devaluate* is a direct equivalent of *devalue,* but it's far less common and may be obsolescent.

> **devaluate** *v.*
>
> *transitive.* = **devalue** *v.*
>
> > 1924   *Glasgow Herald* 1 Mar. 8   The country has gone a great length in the direction of devaluating the vote by conferring it on men whose politics are as immature as themselves.

The word was added in 1933 and the entry was last updated in 1988. That there are no citations added from the period after 1933 may be significant.

The author is Swedish, and in the extract allowed on to Google Books there is no indication of the book's original language, although it has been translated into a number of languages. Using *devaluate* could be an affectation of the author or his translator; it doesn't appear to be a false friend of a Swedish word. That the word appears in MW but not in a common English dictionary like Cambridge might indicate an American influence in the English used. MW's citations are more recent, but from American sources.

It's certainly unusual, but it's not actually wrong.

Comment: According to Ngram, "devaluated" had a certain vogue from 1930 to 1980.  But it was never more popular than "devalued".

Answer (score 0):

The only time I have come across the word "devaluated" is in the recording of *Yes, we have no bananas* by Spike Jones and his City Slickers, which I believe was recorded in 1950. It contains the line "and pounds of devaluated pounds",which like most of this version's other lyrics is not found in the original 1920s song.

It was a topical reference to the 30% devaluation of the UK pound in 1949, and the choice of word was probably made to improve the singability of the line.

For me, "devalued" would always be the word of choice.

My sources are:

1. My personal copy of the 1978 LP *Showcase*;
2. https://history.stackexchange.com/questions/11010/what-factors-led-to-the-30-devaluation-of-pound-sterling-in-1949;
3. Earlier recordings available on the internet.